# Safari (Mac and iOS) does not permit functions named "". Does this break the spec?

Tags: javascript

Safari (Mac and iOS) does not permit functions named "" ([U+1D6AB](https://codepoints.net/U+1D6AB), Mathematical Bold Greek Capital Delta).

AFAIK, Valid identifiers [must](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6) have [the derived core property "ID_Start"](https://codepoints.net/search?IDS=1).

"" [appears to](https://mothereff.in/js-variables#%F0%9D%9D%99) [meet this criteria](https://codepoints.net/search?IDS=1).

Does this break the spec?

```js
function (a, b) {
  return a-b
}
console.log((2, 1)) // 1 in Chrome and FF; "Script error" in Safari
```

Interestingly, Safari does accept "Δ" ([U+0394](https://codepoints.net/U+0394), Greek Capital Letter Delta) as a valid identifier:

```js
function Δ(a, b) {
  return a-b
}
console.log(Δ(2, 1)) // 1 in Chrome and FF and Safari
```

I think it might be something to do with the former character being in the Astral Plane.

Comment: You're having way too much fun

Comment: looks like a bug to me 

Comment: Who cares? Don't do this.

Comment: Spec compliance matters, otherwise what is the point of the spec?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is [the bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208998). It was fixed in March and (presumably) hasn't made it out into released versions of browsers.